# C# WinForms - Button on Form2, to hide Form1

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have 2 Forms:

- Form1
- Form2

There is a button on Form2, that I'd like to have hide Form1 when clicked.

**Button Click from Button in Form2**

```
var mainFrm = new Form1();
mainFrm.Hide();
```

This does nothing. I'm obviously missing something, but can't seem to figure it out.

Any help is definitely appreciated!

Comment: Why are you creating a new instance of Form1 `var mainFrm = new Form1();` ? If your intent was to hide a Form1 that was already being displayed, then you need to get a handle on that already existing form and call Hide() on it.

Answer (score 0):

If your form1 is already present in the page, then why do you need to initialize it again? Just set the visible status to false to hide it.

```
mainFrm.Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

without seeing more of the code it's hard to answer, but you definitely need to reference the the old `Form1` that is already visible and hide it. You are creating a new form and hiding it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your Form2 class to store the reference to the main form.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    /* reference to the main form will be stored here */
    private Form1 _mainForm;

    public Form2(Form1 mainForm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        /* Initialize the main form field */
        this._mainForm = mainForm;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /* Set the main form visibility to false */
        _mainForm.Visible = false;
    } 
}
```

Now when you are creating the Form2 instance just add the main form to the constructor:

```
 /* Show the form2 */
 _form2 = new Form2(this);
 _form2.Show();
```

Note: ***this*** will refer to the form that creates the Form2 object.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a static form type property in your Form1 and set it when Form1 is Shown, and then use it to hide your form
 Here is a code that worked for me.

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var objForm1 = new Form1();
        Form1.Fom1ref = objForm1;
        objForm1.Show();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1.Fom1ref.Hide();

    }
```

Here is the property that should be set in Form1.

```
   public static Form Fom1ref { get; set; }
```